# Replacing url to the desired custom url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

how to change my url in .htaccess file?
Example I have a url :

> www.mysite.com/folder1/index.php?category=cs

I want it to appear like:

> www.mysite.com/folder1/cs

any suggestions please :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /folder1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i pasted this code in my .htaccess file but nothing happened. url still appears as i mentioned above. Can u pls explain where the url is changed in the code you have provided above????

Comment: The RewriteRule line is what you're looking for. What happens when you access www.mysite.com/folder1/cs? Or, do you need to redirect from www.mysite.com/folder1/index.php?category=cs to www.mysite.com/folder1/cs.

Comment: I am actually hitting to  www.mysite.com/folder1/index.php?category=cs but i want it to appear as www.mysite.com/folder1/cs inn the url. I dont want any redirection. I just need to display a different and modified url when such sort of parameters are passed in url. Hope u get it :)

Comment: The code i posted will allow you to route www.mysite.com/folder1/cs to www.mysite.com/folder1/index.php?category=cs without a redirect. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Vlad, this REQUEST_FILENAME need to be replaced by the url on which the rewritting need to be done? for example I have an url 
www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/index.php?qid=26
and I want it to display it like 
www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/26
so what should be the changes in the above code. Kindly rewrite the code according to the url